# Writing to an external file before a blackout

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, backup

I have a python scoreboard program running on a raspberry pi, and I need it to recover the information on it after coming back from a blackout(quite frequent where I live). Below is the code for the saving mechanism only:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

if os.path.isfile('backup.txt'):
    print('Reloading details from previous game... ')
    backup = open('backup.txt', 'r')

    time_a = float(backup.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    team1name = backup.readline().rstrip('\n').upper()
    team2name = backup.readline().rstrip('\n').upper()
    team1score = int(backup.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    team2score = int(backup.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    currentperiod = int(backup.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    team1fouls = int(backup.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    team2fouls = int(backup.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    possesion = bool(backup.readline().rstrip('\n'))

pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 100)

while True:  # Main loop
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == USEREVENT + 1:  # Write to backup file
            backup = open('backup.txt', 'w')
            backup.write('{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(
                str(time_a), team1name, team2name, str(team1score), str(team2score),
                str(currentperiod), str(team1fouls), str(team2fouls), str(possesion)))
            pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 100)

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                backup.close()
                os.remove('backup.txt')
                sys.exit()
```

If I simulate a blackout by doing `kill -9 processID`, then re-run the program, nothing is wrong. But if I simulate a blackout by pulling the plug on my pi, `backup.txt` is empty.

I have tried changing the frequency of the saves (`USEREVENT+1`).

How can I get the program to save to `backup.txt` before an actual blackout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing directly to disk instead of to the buffer solves the problem. Do:

```
backup.flush()
os.fsync(backup.fileno())
```